# Open Ports on LAN

Tags: 12.04, vlc, lan, clementine

I am trying to use VLC remote for Android and Clementine remote for Android.
VLC is configured properly with hosts allowed.
My laptop IP is also DMZ in the router.
I am still getting an error when trying to connect from Android.

Is there a way to check if port 5500 and 8080 is accepting LAN traffic ?

EDIT: Other services such as `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` on any port does not work

This is ElementaryOS Luna (Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to check if a port is open and listening for connections is using `netstat` as follows:

```
netstat -ntlp | grep <port_no>
```

so if you want to check if port no 5500 is open and listening for connections, so:

```
netstat -ntlp | grep 5500
```

If the output is:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::5050                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

then the port is open and listening, if you get an output such as this:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```

Try using

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 5050
```

and if you get no output, port no 5050 is closed and you need a server to accept connections to that port no and open it for clients to be able to connect to that port.

Comment: Thanks, Ports are listening to incoming traffic
Still this does not work.

Comment: @AkshBriZmohun: You need to analyze what the error exactly is and depending upon that take steps ahead. However, I see that you have edited your question and its about Elementary OS, which is off-topic here and should be on unix.stackexchange.com.